# NodeJS no output from python child

Tags: python, node.js

I am using nodeJS to output the result of a python script to an API. The goal of this endpoint is to retrieve the names of the .csv files in the directory.

main script looks like this :

```
if(usefunc == "getallfiles"):
    files = smartbus.get_all_files()
    print(files)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return files
```

```
def get_all_files():
    files = []
    filesstring = ''
    files = glob.glob('./**.csv')
    for file in files :
        filesstring += file
    return filesstring
```

The node.js code looks like this :

```
exports.pythonGet = (req,res,next) =>{
    

    const child = execFile('python3', ['/path/main.py','getallfiles'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
 
      try{
      resultat = stdout;
      console.log(resultat);
      res.send(resultat);
      }
      catch(e){
        console.error(e);
        res.sendStatus(404);

      }
    });
}
```

When executing the python script it works just fine and prints the string containing the names.
But when executing through a request, response is empty.

Also, when setting the filesstring variable manually likes so :

```
def get_all_files():
    files = []
    filesstring = ''
    files = glob.glob('./**.csv')
    for file in files :
        filesstring += file
    filesstring = "blabla"
    return filesstring
```

The code works just fine and the HTTP response contains "blabla"

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here ?

Comment: Why dont you just create nodejs function that does this, that very simple

Comment: it's for a project, the idea was to learn nodeJS and Python. The Python script implements many other functions too.